# AngularJS chaining select

Tags: angularjs, select, chaining

I'm trying to implement that chained select, but chains aren't working properly.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ndm7PFGK8akdaHra7Fdm?p=preview

What I want, need: e.g. when selecting 'alpargatas' as category, and with any listed brand selected, the category should be still selected as 'alpargatas' or when selecting 'Calvin Klein' as brand, and with any listed category selected, the brand should be still selected as 'Calvin Klein'.

Any solution, tip or advice?! Tks in advance

Comment: Why did you delete your previous post about this? Also, SO posts are expected to contain code pertaining to the issue and/or showing what you tried, not just links to a demo.

Comment: Im sorry 4 that. Im newbie here. ;ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) in correct order.

For `category` dropdown

1. add a filter by `brand` like `filter:{brand: filterObject.brand}: true//pass true for strict mode`
2. then the `unique` filter like `unique: 'category'`
3. and last the `orderBy` filter like `orderBy:'category'`

In `HTML`, it looks like

```
<select ng-model="filterObject.category" 
        ng-options="c.category as c.category for c in shoes|filter:{brand: filterObject.brand}: true| unique: 'category'| orderBy:'category'">
<option value="" ng-value="undefined">-- Category:</option>
```

Similar for `Brand` dropdown

```
<select ng-model="filterObject.brand" 
        ng-options="b.brand as b.brand for b in shoes|filter:{category: filterObject.category}: true| unique: 'brand'| orderBy:'brand'">
<option value="" ng-value="undefined">-- Brand:</option>
```

Look both `dropdowns` are bind with your main data source `$scope.shoes` so you don't need the additional filter in your controller.

check the updated [**plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/bODOR9jWTGe6O0f2Z7tv?p=preview)

**Note** As @m59 mentioned you shouldn't delete your post when you are looking for an answer.